# How to implement Binary (TYPE I) for FTP

Tags: c++, gcc, ftp

I need to set up TYPE  command; mode is either ‘I’ (for image), or ‘A’ (for ASCII).  To test the image/binary mode, try transferring a jpg/png image file from the FTP server. (create own FTP server)

However, I'm not sure how to do this, some code below. I pretty much somewhat copied the stor/put command - which works

Currently, when i attempt to get an image from the localhost, the image i receive is 0 byes in size.

Also note:  bytes = recv(ns, &receive_buffer[n], 1, 0);//receive byte by byte... is in my skeleton/start up code.

...

```
if(strncmp(receive_buffer,"TYPE",4) == 0){ //attempt
         int bytesRecieved1 = 0;
        char codeStr[250];
        sscanf(receive_buffer,"TYPE %c\r\n",codeStr);
        char code = codeStr[0];
         char tempBuff[SEGMENT_SIZE];
        memset(tempBuff,0, sizeof(tempBuff));
        int _bytes1 = 0;
        switch(code){
            case 'I': //
                sprintf(send_buffer, "200 Switching to Binary mode\r\n");
                 while (1){
                if(active == 0) {
                    _bytes1 = recv(ns, &receive_buffer[n], 1, 0);
                }else{
                    _bytes1 = recv(ns, &receive_buffer[n], 1, 0);
                }

                if (_bytes1 < 0) {
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"226 Successfully received %d bytes\r\n",bytesRecieved1);
                    bytes = sendString(&ns,send_buffer);
                    printf("Success");
                    break;
                    bytesRecieved1 += _bytes1;
                }
            }
        }
        bytes = sendString(&ns,send_buffer);
        return;
    }
```

...

Should be able to see the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to respond to `TYPE` command by initiating a file transfer. That's what you should do only after you receive `STOR` command.

To implement `TYPE` command, you simply respond `200 OK` and internally remember that you need to use binary (or ascii) mode for the upcoming file transfer (once you receive `STOR` or `RETR`).